# project files lost from eclipse workspace, log file shows exception

Tags: eclipse

I had a project n my workspace few days back. 
Now, when I opened eclipse, the project is still there.
But it no more contains the whole package structure and the files. The bin folder is containing one .project file and the file are lost from the workspace file system as well.

Looking at the log file, there is one exception:
org.eclipse.sore.internal.resources.ResourceException:file not found

also there is an error message:
The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session: refreshing workspace to recover changes.

Is there any way to restore my project? If somene knows..Please help

Comment: Sounds to me like your project wasn't stored in the workspace and now eclipse has lost the metadata of its location. Are you sure it was on the workspace folder from the beginning?

Comment: yes, I created the project in the workspace folder only

Comment: well, if you are confident that the source files are not where they should be, then run a data recovery tool.

Comment: Right click on the project and select `Restore from Local History...` to see if Eclipse has any versions of your code in the history.

Comment: no, there are no versions in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The .project in the bin folder is a problem.  That file ought to be in the project root directory.  If it's in the bin folder then it sounds like Eclipse was treating the bin directory as the root and that's not good.

From Eclipse, select the project (not the .project) and view the properties via the context menu.  The properties dialog will show you where Eclipse thinks the project is.  It doesn't look good for the project, but try manually moving the .project to where Eclipse thinks the root directory should be and do a refresh.

Comment: I provided the .project file at the required location and removed from bin but it did not restore the package structure and files

Comment: @user2971387 The package structure comes from the .classpath file which should be in the root directory along with the .project file